# How best to store map / array data in Swift for use in Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Attempting to figure out how best to structure data in a Swift project for sending and retrieving from Firestore. I've seen a number of responses on this topic, but I am still not quite clear on how best to handle the relevance of structs with Firestore's maps / arrays. In a perfect scenario, it'd be nice if a Table was stored as a single document in the FS DB, with an array or map of the various rows. But these rows also have multiple key to value pairs.

Upon structuring, it seems like having it befit how Firestore handles data would be ideal rather than having to create some sort of parsing scenario (specifically for the rows). Thanks to anyone out there that has a peek.

```
struct Row {
    var rangeBegin: Int
    var rangeEnd: Int
    var content: String
}

struct Table {
    var title: String
    var sequencing: String
    var time: Date
    var rows: [Row]
}
```

## EDIT:

So, here's more detail on how I'd end up structuring or needing to query the data...

```
Table
- Table Title (String)
- Rows (Array of Rows)

Row
- Row Content (String)
- Row Order (Int)

Table Group
- Table Group Title (String)
- Tables (Array of Tables)
```

User has a dashboard with a list of Tables (showing the Table Titles). They may decide to group tables into a Table Group (but this is tertiary). Ultimately, when a user goes to a detail view of a table, it will load the Table Title, and below list all of the Rows associated with that content in the correct order.

Upon changing a Row Content line, the table data will be updated / saved to the DB. Same with changing the Table Title.

If the user Creates a new table, they will be taken to an empty detail view with a Table Title Placeholder and a Row 1 Content Placeholder. Upon filling out these, a table will be saved. So textInput off focus would save for the most part.

Hope this scenario helps.

Comment: There is not necessarily a "best way" to model arbitrary data in Firestore.  The modeling should follow from the way you intend to query the data.  Without knowing your queries ahead of time, you might make a decision that leads to a problem later on.  Figure out your queries first, then model your data to suit those queries, taking into account the known limitations of Firestore.

Comment: @DougStevenson that's excellent feedback, considering it gives me homework rather than a solution. It also makes sense, because I'm in the process of creating a few queries, and I keep going back and forth based on what's working there and what's not. Ultimately, queries may be things like, editing content on one textInput for a single Row.content string, may trigger the DB needing to update that one particular key value in FS. Updating the Table.title string, as well... essentially as soon as the user unfocused the input.

Comment: Is it considered bad practice in Firestore to define a field called "row" as a Map, and then within it have multiple "row1" as a Map, "row2" as a Map, and so on?

Comment: It's probably best to think about Firebase as Collections, Documents and Fields; 'row', 'column' and 'table' constructs don't really exist in NoSQL land. Your question mentions *query the data*; that's a significant driving factor into how data is structured. However, you've not told us what your data is or what you want to get out of it. *I have a list of items and want to query for every item that's blue* gives us more to work with. Can you replace abstract's with real-world examples? Lastly, UI and Firebase structures are kinda unrelated so think MVC with Firebase being part of the M)odel.